# @DataJpaTest stops working with @Profile annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I want to have JPA test using specific spring test profile. But somehow it's failing to load spring context.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Profile("myTestProfile")
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestingConfig.class, MyJpaConfig.class})
public class JpaPlusOtherStuffTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private MyJpaRepository myJpaRepository;
}
```

Fails with following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'myJpaRepository': 
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5e77f0f4' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5e77f0f4': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
```

If I remove `@Profile` annotation then test works fine. I just don't understand how additional profile fails `@DataJpaTest` to be run. Maybe somebody could explain this to me?

**UPD**
Here is my `MyJpaConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mycompany.project.jpa")
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MyJpaConfig {
}
```

Comment: may you post your spring configuration?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata added. Other configuration is doesn't matter. Might be empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `@Profile` *marks* the `DataJpaTest`'s inherited Configuration as being part of profile `myTestProfile`. However, you did not activate any profile, so `DataJpaTest` is being ignored.

To activate a profile, you rather need to use `@ActiveProfile`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("myTestProfile")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestingConfig.class, MyJpaConfig.class})
public class JpaPlusOtherStuffTest {
}
```

I suppose the purpose of all this is to have `TestingConfig` only enabled when running unit test ? This is where you need to add the `@Profile` annotation:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("myTestProfile")
public class TestingConfig {
}
```

Comment: Yes my test config looks like you wrote. Now it works! I was just using wrong annotation. Thanks!